# How do I change ownership of a folder in my downloads folder?

Tags: directory, ownership

I have a folder in /home/downloads that's called wonderdraft. I wish for this folder to be owned by my user. How do I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If currently you are the owner of this folder (or you have the permissions) and you want to change it to another user
then you can use

```
chown user /home/downloads/folder
```

If you are not owner of this folder then you have to become root or user `sudo` command to change the owner

```
sudo chown user /home/downloads/folder
```